# Toggle button state from inside a class (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I need to build my own switch/button that has either an on or off state, and I want it as an object so I can make many. But draw() / constant loop makes it difficult to set a state. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let s;
    
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background('gray');
  
  s = new Switch(100,100);  
}

function draw() {
  s.draw();
}


function mousePressed(status) {
    if (status === false) { 
      return true;
    } else if (status === true) {
      return false;
    }  
}

class Switch {
  constructor(x,y) {
    this.status = true;
    this.statusColour = 'black';
    this.pos = createVector(x,y);
    this.size = 100;
  }
  
  intersect() {
    if ((mouseX >= this.pos.x && mouseX <= this.pos.x+this.size) && (mouseY >= this.pos.y && mouseY <= this.pos.y+this.size)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  draw() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.statusColour);
    rect(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.size,this.size);
    
    // Action to make switch
    this.intersect() ? this.status = mousePressed(this.status) : null;
    
    
    this.status === true ? this.statusColour = 'green' : this.statusColour = 'black';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the wrong way around. [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) is an event callback. It is invoked by the system. Never call it directly. When the mouse is pressed, the event callback function `mousPressed()` is called.

Add a method to the class `Switch`, which topples the button:

```js
class Switch {
    // [...]

    switchState() {
        if (this.intersect()) {
            this.status = !this.status;
            this.statusColour = this.status ? 'black' : 'green';
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Delegate the mouse callback to this method:

```js
function mousePressed(status) {
    s.switchState();
}
```

See the example:

```js
let s;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background('gray');

    s = new Switch(100,100);  
}

function draw() {
    s.draw();
}

function mousePressed(status) {
    s.switchState();
}

class Switch {
    constructor(x,y) {
      this.status = true;
      this.statusColour = 'black';
      this.pos = createVector(x,y);
      this.size = 100;
    }

    intersect() {
        return mouseX >= this.pos.x && mouseX <= this.pos.x+this.size && mouseY >= this.pos.y && mouseY <= this.pos.y+this.size;
    }

    switchState() {
        if (this.intersect()) {
            this.status = !this.status;
            this.statusColour = this.status ? 'black' : 'green';
        }
    }

    draw() {
        noStroke();
        fill(this.statusColour);
        rect(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.size,this.size);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for this and for taking the time to explain!